# Random color to fill triangles in java

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, awt, java-2d

I am creating an application that draws 5 random triangles of different random colors. The random drawing of triangles work but for some reason the triangles are all the same color, sometimes having different colors where the triangles intersect. Here is a picture:

[image of what the application creates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDpba.png)

Does anyone know how to fix this issue and make it so that each triangle will be a different color?

TrianglesJPanel.java:

```
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.GeneralPath;
import java.util.Random;

public class TrianglesJPanel extends JPanel 
{
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        //call superclass's paintComponent
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Random random = new Random();

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        GeneralPath triangle = new GeneralPath();  //create general path object

        //get the height and width
        int height = this.getHeight();
        int width = this.getWidth();

        int[] x = new int[3];
        int[] y = new int[3];

        //draw 5 random triangles in application frame that can be adjusted
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            //get random points on the panel
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                x[j] = random.nextInt(width + 1); //random number from 0 to width
                y[j] = random.nextInt(height + 1);  //random number from 0 to height
                //Ex. Frame 500x500: x could be from 0 to 500, y from 0 to 500
            }

            triangle.moveTo(x[0], y[0]);  //start pos
            triangle.lineTo(x[1], y[1]);  //2nd point
            triangle.lineTo(x[2], y[2]);  //3rd point
            triangle.lineTo(x[0], y[0]);  //back to start pos
            triangle.closePath();         //close the triangle

            System.out.println(g2.getColor());
            //set random color for triangle
            g2.setColor(new Color(random.nextInt(256), random.nextInt(256), random.nextInt(256)));

            g2.fill(triangle);  //draw filled triangle
        }
    }
}
```

Triangle.java:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Triangles
{
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        //choose title
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Drawing random triangles");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //drawing done on JPanel, embedded in a JFrame
        TrianglesJPanel triangle = new TrianglesJPanel();
        frame.add(triangle);               //add the triangles to frame
        frame.setBackground(Color.WHITE);   //set background of frame to white color
        frame.setSize(500,500);    //set frame size to 500x500
        frame.setVisible(true);    //display frame
    }
}
```

Comment: How about storing all the colors that you already used in a list? When generating a new random color, you can simply check if it already has been used. Another option would be to cycle through a predefined list of colors.

Comment: You could also set the color by using `g2.setColor(new Color(random.nextInt(1<<24)))`  This uses the `Color` constructor that takes an `int` as an argument.  And the high order byte (alpha) is still set to `255`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Triangles share the same GeneralPath object, and it is being filled with the last color used. To solve this you need a new GeneralPath object for *each* triangle

so:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    // GeneralPath triangle = new GeneralPath();  //create general path object
    int height = this.getHeight();
    int width = this.getWidth();
    int[] x = new int[3];
    int[] y = new int[3];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            x[j] = random.nextInt(width + 1); //random number from 0 to width
            y[j] = random.nextInt(height + 1);  //random number from 0 to height
        }
        GeneralPath triangle = new GeneralPath();
        triangle.moveTo(x[0], y[0]);  //start pos
        triangle.lineTo(x[1], y[1]);  //2nd point
        triangle.lineTo(x[2], y[2]);  //3rd point
        triangle.lineTo(x[0], y[0]);  //back to start pos
        triangle.closePath();         //close the triangle
        System.out.println(g2.getColor());
        g2.setColor(new Color(random.nextInt(256), random.nextInt(256), random.nextInt(256)));
        g2.fill(triangle);  //draw filled triangle
    }
}
```

Comment: `triangle.reset()` is another option (although I haven't tried it).

Comment: @WJS: try it first

Answer (score 3):

The answer was already provided but here are some other suggestions.

- Don't draw a line back to `x[0], y[0]`.  That's closePath's job.
- Use renderingHints to average out the edges to make them appear smoother.

```
   g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
```

- If you want the Frame to be centered on the screen you can do this.

```
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
```

- And finally, declare x and y as `floats` or `doubles`.  It probably isn't making any difference but one should be consistent with expected types when possible.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions, ill definitely implement those.

Comment: *"Use renderingHints to average out the edges"* That doesn't work when using `fill` for a geometric shape (or at least, it didn't last time I checked). So to fix that, I always `draw` the shape directly after filling it.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I just tried it and it appears to work with the above example.  The normally saw toothed edges are smoother.  Two possibilities.  1) they fixed it.  2) I misunderstood what you were saying (the latter is more likely :) )

Comment: @WJS I may have been mistaken all along, but just confirmed your result as well.